# request.get method is not working for few specific websites in AWS Lambda Python shell

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute request.get( ) method for few web urls. And the code is executing perfectly in my local system pycharm, jupyter notebook, google colab notebook etc. Only when I am executing the code in AWS Lambda function, it's working for few urls and throwing timeout exception for other urls.
the list of urls are:

1. 'https://www.google.com/'
2. 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
3. 'https://www.nseindia.com/'
4. 'https://www.makemytrip.com/'

The code I've developed is

```
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url1 = 'https://www.google.com/'
    url2 = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
    url3 = 'https://www.nseindia.com/'
    url4 = 'https://www.makemytrip.com/'
    header = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }
    response = requests.get(url=url3, headers=header,allow_redirects=False,timeout=60) 
    for i in response.cookies: 
        print(i.name +"==>>", i.value)
    return
```

The code is working for url1 and url2 but not working for url3 and url4 in AWS Lambda python shell only, but all the urls are working in google colab or jupyter notebook.

Comment: It could be that the site you're accessing is blocking AWS IP. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64871941/533711

Comment: I read the link you shared. If the website is blocking AWS Ip, then how can I build a solution in AWS where requests.get() works.

Comment: "If the website is blocking AWS Ip, then how can I build a solution in AWS where requests.get() works." You can't. That's like asking how to get in somebody's house if they locked the door because they don't want you in their house. The owners of those websites have every right to block you from accessing the website if they don't want you accessing it through some automated tool like AWS Lambda.

Comment: Understood. But is there any way, may be by using some api, so that I can fetch the stock data in AWS?

Comment: @SaptarsiBasu: the NSE terms of use include this clause: "You should not conduct any systematic or automated data collection activities (including scraping, data mining, data extraction and data harvesting) on or in relation to our website.". The website is using technical measures to enforce this clause. Are you asking us to help you bypass these measures and get unauthorized access to the website?

Comment: I don't have intention to make any unauthorized access to any website, FYI @Quassnoi. I was asking "If there is any technical way so that I can extract the cookie information for a POC purpose. And I don't mind whether the website is nseindia or makemytrip. If you read my question properly I've mentioned 4 urls. I experienced that the first 2 urls were working but the other 2 urls not. Where outside AWS env. all the urls working, So I wanted to understand the root cause of it. And also tried to enquire if there is any technical way to fetch the json response for those 2 urls.

Comment: @Quassnoi, without understanding the entire scenario you should not have instigated others to close this questionnaire. How did you ensure from your end that I am asking for an unauthorized access to a website in a public forum?

Comment: @SaptarsiBasu: the root cause is that they blocked access from AWS by IP. It's a technical measure to enforce a clause in their TOS that forbids their website data from being scraped. Access to a website in violation of TOS is unauthorized access. You are looking for a technical way to circumvent this measure and get unauthorized access. I'm not judging you, but I don't think that questions asking for that should be on StackOverflow. To this end, I left a vote to close this question.